# Can I use projection in queryDSL for embeddable with OneToMany?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have an entity like this

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private ItemList itemList;
}

@Embeddable
public class ItemList {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<Item> itemList;

}
```

When I try to get ItemList using queryDSL below:

```java
JPAQueryFactory query = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
QOrder o = QOrder.order;

return query.select(o.itemList)
            .from(o)
            .fetch();
```

It generates the error...

```
Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Is there a way to select Embeddable class directly at queryDSL?

Comment: Try replacing orderLine with itemList.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling Sorry, it' just a typo. Same exception is still generated

Comment: what is the return type? if the type is List<Item>, you should change ItemList Object.